# ASP.NET JQuery Plugin inside UpdatePanel in UserControl

Tags: asp.net

I am writing the javascript code to initialize a jquery plugin in my user control from the .ascx.cs file to be able to modify some options when I reload the plugin. Each time the plugin is loaded, I update a div with the new generated code. It is working fine, I can see the code updating but it is not being executed so my plugin does not take in consideration the new options.

ascx file :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="div_js" runat="server">

        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ascx.cs file :

```
div_js.InnerHtml = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
    + "$(document).ready(function() {"
        + "$('#Grille_" + ID + "').DataTable({ etc ...
```

So the javascript should be executed when the page finished loading.

Comment: Is it because the page is not reloaded and only my plugin is updated ? Is there something like "$(document).ready()" but just when a part of the page is loaded ?

Comment: see the answer on the other question, is the same solution with yours

Comment: in the `function EndRequest` you initialize again your javascript code

Comment: I was already doing the following but it is not working (initialization / getInstance / add_endRequest) : var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();prm.add_endRequest(function () {

Comment: I think that I have found my real problem. I thought that the properties of my user control were saved but it seems they are not, it seems that I have to use ViewState but I do not know how it works.